How to insert tokens into cookies in OpenIdConnect
I am using OpenIddict to implement authentication and authorization in my IdentityServer and I need to insert access_token and refresh_token into cookies. I have a class that extends IOpenIddictServerHandler<OpenIddictServerEvents.HandleTokenRequestContext>. In this class I intercept tokens and try to set them into cookies and then remove them from the response body. But they are not set into cookies, nothing happens, but the removal is successful. IdentityServer is used with react-client and api
CustomTokenEndpointHandler code:
using OpenIddict.Abstractions;
using OpenIddict.Server;


namespace Company.WebApi.CustomToken;

public class CustomTokenEndpointHandler : IOpenIddictServerHandler<OpenIddictServerEvents.HandleTokenRequestContext>
{
    private readonly IHttpContextAccessor _httpContextAccessor;

    public CustomTokenEndpointHandler(IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor)
    {
        _httpContextAccessor = httpContextAccessor;
    }

    public async ValueTask HandleAsync(OpenIddictServerEvents.HandleTokenRequestContext context)
    {
        if (context.Request == null)
        {
            throw new NullReferenceException("Request missing in HandleTokenRequestContext");
        }

        var clientId = context.Request.ClientId;
        if (clientId != "logistic_company_react_client")
        {
            await ValueTask.CompletedTask;
            return;
        }

        var accessToken = context.Transaction.Response?.GetParameter(OpenIddictConstants.Parameters.AccessToken)?.ToString();
        var refreshToken = context.Transaction.Response?.GetParameter(OpenIddictConstants.Parameters.RefreshToken)?.ToString();

        _httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.Response.OnStarting(() =>
        {
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(accessToken))
            {
                _httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.Response.Cookies.Append("access_token", accessToken, new CookieOptions
                {
                    HttpOnly = true, 
                    Secure = false,  
                    SameSite = SameSiteMode.Lax, 
                    Expires = DateTimeOffset.UtcNow.AddHours(1) 
                });
            }

            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(refreshToken))
            {
                _httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.Response.Cookies.Append("refresh_token", refreshToken, new CookieOptions
                {
                    HttpOnly = true, 
                    Secure = false,  
                    SameSite = SameSiteMode.Lax,
                    Expires = DateTimeOffset.UtcNow.AddDays(7) 
                });
            }

            context.Transaction.Response?.RemoveParameter(OpenIddictConstants.Parameters.AccessToken);
            context.Transaction.Response?.RemoveParameter(OpenIddictConstants.Parameters.RefreshToken);

            return Task.CompletedTask;
        });

        await ValueTask.CompletedTask;
    }
}

Event handler code connection fragment:
 services.AddHttpContextAccessor();

 services.AddOpenIddict()
 .AddServer(options =>
 {
     options.AddEventHandler<OpenIddictServerEvents.HandleTokenRequestContext>(
         builder => builder.UseScopedHandler<CustomTokenEndpointHandler>());
  ...
 }

Get token method:
[HttpPost("~/connect/token")]
public async Task<IActionResult> Exchange(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    var request = HttpContext.GetOpenIddictServerRequest();

    if (request is null)
    {
        return Problem(ApplicationErrors.SpecifiedGrantTypeNotSupported.Name);
    }

    if (request.IsAuthorizationCodeGrantType() || request.IsRefreshTokenGrantType())
    {
        ClaimsPrincipal claimsPrincipal = (await HttpContext.AuthenticateAsync(OpenIddictServerAspNetCoreDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)).Principal;

        var command = new TokenQuery(claimsPrincipal, request);

        var result = await _sender.Send(command, cancellationToken); //here i get ClaimsIdentity

        if (result.IsFailure && result.Error.Code == "User.CannotFindUserFromToken")
        {
            return Forbid(
                authenticationSchemes: OpenIddictServerAspNetCoreDefaults.AuthenticationScheme,
                properties: new AuthenticationProperties(new Dictionary<string, string?>
                {
                    [OpenIddictServerAspNetCoreConstants.Properties.Error] = Errors.InvalidGrant,
                    [OpenIddictServerAspNetCoreConstants.Properties.ErrorDescription] = result.Error.Name
                }));
        }


        return SignIn(new ClaimsPrincipal(result.Value.ClaimsIdentity), OpenIddictServerAspNetCoreDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
    }

    throw new InvalidOperationException("The specified grant type is not supported.");
}


You are misssing context.Transaction.Response?.SetParameter like below.
context.Transaction.Response?.SetParameter(OpenIddictConstants.Parameters.AccessToken, 
accessToken);
context.Transaction.Response?.SetParameter(OpenIddictConstants.Parameters.RefreshToken, refreshToken);


Here is my Test Code.
public class CustomTokenEndpointHandler : IOpenIddictServerHandler<OpenIddictServerEvents.HandleTokenRequestContext>
{
    private readonly IHttpContextAccessor _httpContextAccessor;

    public CustomTokenEndpointHandler(IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor)
    {
        _httpContextAccessor = httpContextAccessor;
    }

    public async ValueTask HandleAsync(OpenIddictServerEvents.HandleTokenRequestContext context)
    {
        if (context.Request == null)
        {
            throw new NullReferenceException("Request missing in HandleTokenRequestContext");
        }

        var clientId = context.Request.ClientId;
        if (clientId != "logistic_company_react_client")
        {
            await ValueTask.CompletedTask;
            return;
        }

        var accessToken = "112233";
        var refreshToken = "445566";

        _httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.Response.OnStarting(() =>
        {
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(accessToken))
            {
                _httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.Response.Cookies.Append("access_token", accessToken, new CookieOptions
                {
                    HttpOnly = true,
                    Secure = false,  
                    SameSite = SameSiteMode.Lax,
                    Expires = DateTimeOffset.UtcNow.AddHours(1)
                });
            }

            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(refreshToken))
            {
                _httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.Response.Cookies.Append("refresh_token", refreshToken, new CookieOptions
                {
                    HttpOnly = true,
                    Secure = false,  
                    SameSite = SameSiteMode.Lax,
                    Expires = DateTimeOffset.UtcNow.AddDays(7)
                });
            }

            context.Transaction.Response?.RemoveParameter(OpenIddictConstants.Parameters.AccessToken);
            context.Transaction.Response?.RemoveParameter(OpenIddictConstants.Parameters.RefreshToken);

            return Task.CompletedTask; 
        });
        // Add these 2 line
        context.Transaction.Response?.SetParameter(OpenIddictConstants.Parameters.AccessToken, accessToken);
        context.Transaction.Response?.SetParameter(OpenIddictConstants.Parameters.RefreshToken, refreshToken);

        await ValueTask.CompletedTask;
    }
}


Hello! Thanks for answer. What context are you using when you call await _customTokenEndpointHandler.HandleAsync(context)? I didn't call this method in the controller. It worked itself

Hi @keks01 I am just creating a api to test it, you can ignore this, here is my test code.

@keks01 Please let me know if my answer useful to you. And I am willing to investigate the issue further with you.

Okay. Is there any way to combine this with the Exchange method I added in the question? It just has SignIn() and it seems to me that it somehow interferes with installing cookies

@keks01 I saw you updated the question, let me check it, will reply you soon.

@keks01 You can check the blogs Implementing the Connect/Token Endpoint first and add custom claims by using ticket.SetProperty. Here is my sample cde, waiting for your updates.
